# How to tell if Milestone triggers are being lost/delayed

Tags: casemilestone, entitlements

We had a vendor setup our Milestones/SLAs for us. Plagued with problems from the get-go, the vendor eventually told us that our problems were all caused by Entitlement Processes queue being maxed out (Setup > Monitor > Entitlement Processes), that they didn't know why and that there was nothing they could do. They then quit the project. I have no idea if this is even accurate, but we do still have a ton of problems with SLAs/Milestones, so I'm trying to figure out the answer to this question:

Is there some way I can know or tell if I am "losing" Milestone triggers? They said because our Milestone triggers were maxed out, when Salesforce was trying to add new ones to the queue, it would sometimes fail, and thus make our milestones super inconsistent. So how can I tell if this is happening?

If it IS happening, do you know any way we could prevent this. We are a fairly small company (20ish people) so I can't even see how we could be approaching the limit.

Any help appreciated. 
[image]

Entitlement Queue[image]

Entitlement Queue

(Entitlement Queue)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @Eric Not yet. I compiled a list of every trigger we have that relates to Milestones and what they're doing and we're seeing how we can cut it down. The conclusion that I arrived at (for now) is that we just have too many triggers, and the simplest solution is to remove them. After I do, we'll review and see how long the delay is.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is nice question, thanks for that.

> You have reached the maximum number (1000) of deletable Entitlement Process Queue at one time

According to [Salesforce Features and Editions Limits Table](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_features.htm)

**Entitlement processes and milestones** - You can create up to 1,000 entitlement processes total, with up to 10 milestones per process. If your org was created before Summer ’13, its maximum entitlement processes can be lower. Contact Salesforce to increase it.

So, work with Salesforce to increase the limit at your org, you can ask to increase for 10 times.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57517/discussion-on-answer-by-santanu-boral-how-to-tell-if-milestone-triggers-are-bein).